# Read from any file in binary mode, append it to string, and send through TCP socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

So I have to send a specific message to a server (which already exists).

This request follows this format:

```
DO dirname number_of_files [file_size file_name file_data]*
```

so for example it can be something like this:

```
DO dir 2 1421 house.png [binary data I assume?] 1239 info.txt [more binary data?]
```

As you can see there can be as many files as you want.

So what I was doing is creating a string where I append all the information and at the end send it all together, but I'm stuck at the data part.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(ip, port)
request = "DO " + directory + " " + str(number_of_files)

for file_number in range(0,number_of_files):
    data = open("./" + directory + "/" + files_info[file_number*2], 'rb').read()
    client_request += " " + " ".join(files_info[file_number*2 : 1 + file_number*2]) + " " + data

s.send((request + "\n").encode())
```

This does not working because I'm trying to append the data which is binary to a string (`TypeError: must be str, not bytes`). I tried using .decode() before appending but I get an utf-8 decoder error (`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`). I tried with utf-16 and ascii and it didn't work either.

Should I be handling this in another way? I have done more requests like this but none of them included data from files, only numbers/strings so it was never a problem before.

I am trying to follow this format because I have all the code right now done like this (and these steps I showed don't all happen in the same functions) so changing the way I send the messages is not optimal

Comment: Surely, `s` can accept bytes if the protocol requires bytes. Please [edit] to show or describe the `s` code.

Comment: It does accept bytes but the problem is converting the file into a string and then into bytes

Comment: You can try read string from file, and convert them into bytes when you want to send.

Comment: Won't this work: Send some text encoded with the agreed upon character encoding, send some bytes, send some text encoded with the agreed upon character encoding, send some bytes, ...

Comment: You do not have to send everything in a single `s.send()`. You can and should send it in pieces. So when it's time to send the data you can just do `s.sendall(data)`. And don't use `socket.send()` unless you are checking the return value and are prepared to resend any unsent bytes.

Comment: @JamesKPolk what should I use instead of .send then?

Comment: @Rouzip that's what I'm trying to do but I haven't been able to without getting errors

Comment: @TomBlodget I was trying to avoid that because of the way I structured the code, but I'll probably just switch it for that if I don't find another solution

Comment: What @Rouzip and you are considering can only be done for a certain character encodings, ones that might not support the characters needed for filenames on a modern OS.

Comment: @Myntekt: you should use `socket.sendall()`

Comment: @JamesKPolk I now have a loop sending multiple pieces of bytes instead of just one (divided the command in different parts). Should I still switch to sendall? Send seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my simple working code to get something close to what you want:

```
import socket

ip = '192.168.10.137'
port = 4043

directory = 'C:/123/'

#with open('1.dat', 'wb') as file:
#    file.write(b'\x00\x01\x1a\xa1')
#with open('2.dat', 'wb') as file:
#    file.write(b'\x00\x01\x00\x00')

file_info = ['1.dat', '2.dat']

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:

    sock.connect((ip, port))

    sock.send(
        'DO {} {}'.format(directory, len(file_info)).encode('UTF-8'))

    for filename in file_info:
        with open(filename, mode='rb') as file:
            data = file.read()
        sock.send(
            ' {} '.format(len(data)).encode('UTF-8'))
        sock.send(
            '{} '.format(filename).encode('UTF-8'))
        sock.send(data)
```

Data received by server (bytes):

```
b'DO C:/123/ 2 4 1.dat \x00\x01\x1a\xa1 4 2.dat \x00\x01\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Looks good. Perhaps you should test a filename like .dat and data that's incompatible with UTF-8 (in case any part of either side might try to intepret the data as text), such as FF FF FF FF.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up changing the whole structure and sending messages like that instead of all together

Comment: @Myntekt You use tcp-protocol so it does not matter if you send data piece by piece or  all pieces altogether. You may create `to_sent = b''`, add every piece to it like `to_sent += 'DO {} {}'.format(directory, len(file_info)).encode('UTF-8')` and then `sock.send(to_sent)` in the very end of `with ... as sock:` suite. It is essentially the same and you will get the same result.

Comment: Yeah I could have done that, but I needed some of the command info later on, so I ended up putting it in a list and encoding it only at the very end (just before sending)